# Having trouble rendering in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, render

I am not able to render the component called Butcher Shop.  I cannot figure out what I am missing in order for it to not be null or undefined. Can anyone spot the mistake? Nothing is printing to the DOM. This is the error I get back : TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined.

> 40 | export class ButcherShop extends React.component{

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const BUTCHER_PRODUCTS = [
  'Tenderloin',
  'Short ribs',
  'Beef shin',
  'Ribeye'
];

export class OlderCoaster extends React.Component {
  render() {
    React.createElement('div', {},
    React.createElement('p', {},"Two grannies having the time of their life!"),
    React.createElement('p', {}, "Passengers:"),
    React.createElement('ul', {},
    [
      React.createElement('li', "Anges"),
      React.createElement('li', {}, "miruel")


    ]));


    return (<div class="oldercoaster"></div>
    );
  };
};
export class InFrontOfYou extends React.Component{
  render() {
    React.createElement('div',{},
  React.createElement('p', {},'You shouldnt look too far'), 
React.createElement('p', {}, 'Sometimes, the soultion is right in from of you'),
);

return (<div></div>);
  };
};

export class ButcherShop extends React.component{
  render() {
    React.createElement('div', {},
  React.createElement('p', {}, 'Hello! We have the following products for sale today'),
React.createElement('ul', {}, 
[
 React.createElement('li', {}, 'Tenderloin'),
 React.createElement('li', {}, 'Short ribs'),
 React.createElement('li', {}, 'Beef shin'),
 React.createElement('li', {}, 'Ribeye') 
]));
return (<div class="butcher-shop"></div>)
  }
}


  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement('div', {}, [
      React.createElement(OlderCoaster),
      React.createElement(InFrontOfYou),
      React.createElement(ButcherShop)
    ]),
    document.getElementById('global')
  );
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `React.Component` on line 40 (as opposed to `React.component`)?

Comment: great catch.  thanks!

Comment: why not use JSX in place of calling JS code. It easy readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple writing error in there, it should be

`export class ButcherShop extends React.Component {`

Notice the uppercase C

Comment: That got rid of the errors, however the page is still blank.  I have a feeling it has to do with the butcher_products array at the top.

Comment: @davidhazlettjr It's because you're not returning the elements you created in your `render` methods. Save all of your `React.createElement` elements into a variable and use that in your `return`:  `return <div class="butcher-shop">{elements}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems, you need to make `class` into `className` also if i put some text inside of `return (<div></div>)` of InFrontOfYou, it renders.  Take a look at your 'return' to see if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Main problem: `Component` should be capitalized:
Also, consider the following syntax

```
    export class ButcherShop extends React.Component{
      render() {
      return 
      <div class="butcher-shop">
       <div>
        <p>'Hello! We have the following products for sale today'</p>
        <ul>
          <li>'Tenderloin'</li>
          <li>'Short ribs'</li>
          <li>'Beef shin'</li>
          <li>'Ribeye'</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not returning the elements you created in your render methods.

Save all of your React.createElement elements into a variable and use that in your return:

```
export class ButcherShop extends React.Component{
    render() {
        const content = React.createElement('div', {},
                React.createElement('p', {}, 'Hello! We have the following products for sale today'),
                React.createElement('ul', {},
                [
                    React.createElement('li', {}, 'Tenderloin'),
                    React.createElement('li', {}, 'Short ribs'),
                    React.createElement('li', {}, 'Beef shin'),
                    React.createElement('li', {}, 'Ribeye')
                ]));
        return <div class="butcher-shop">{content}</div>
    }
}
```

Look at how you are rendering your app, you are returning the object from `React.createElement`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement('div', {}, [
      React.createElement(OlderCoaster),
      React.createElement(InFrontOfYou),
      React.createElement(ButcherShop)
    ]),
    document.getElementById('global')
  );
```

Your components render method works the same way. You need to actually return the elements you create.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you better use JSX. 
I leave a link for you to learn to use it:
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html.
Here is an example of how your code would look with JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const BUTCHER_PRODUCTS = [
'Tenderloin',
'Short ribs',
'Beef shin',
'Ribeye'
];

export class OlderCoaster extends React.Component {
render(){
 return(
    <div className="oldercoaster">
        <p>Two grannies having the time of their life!</p>
        <p>Passengers:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Anges</li>
            <li>miruel</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 )}};

 export class InFrontOfYou extends React.Component{
 render() {
  return(
    <div>
        <p>You shouldnt look too far</p>
        <p>Sometimes, the soultion is right in from of you</p>
    </div>
    )
  );
  };

  export class ButcherShop extends React.Component{
   render() {
    return(
      <div className="butcher-shop">
      <p>Hello! We have the following products for sale today</p>
      <ul>
          <li>Tenderloin</li>
          <li>Short ribs</li>
          <li>Beef shin</li>
          <li>Ribeye</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   )
 }

   ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
      <OlderCoaster/>
      <InFrontOfYou/>
      <ButcherShop/>
  </div>,
document.getElementById('global')
);
```